# Store persistent data without a web server for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Is there any way to store persistent data for Chrome Extensions without using a web server?

Is Chrome storage persistent? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

I want to avoid the costs of a server, but I also don't think localStorage is good enough because the user can delete it.

In fact, the only persistent data I need to store is the accounts that have logged into the extension on the device itself, so that info might be stored by Google's servers already?

Comment: There is article about it: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage

Answer (score 1):

I don`t think there is an non-server way to store extension data without user being able to modify it.

However there are lot of great services that offer free plans for many platforms eg. [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com)

Comment: what about chrome storage? Is it persistent? Or can it also be deleted by the user? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage